# "Easing" Transitions in Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

Currently when I animate a surface in matplotlib, I generate snapshots manually and stitch together with `ImageMagick`. This is similar to the standard matplotlib animation in that it does not transition between the two frames.

Can I ease (in D3js terminology, and I'm sure of industry terminology more broadly - linear/cubic easing) during the transition? Or, is there a function in numpy to interpolate between two frames (the two surfaces) and end with a transition?

A simple example would be transitioning from the matplotlib example to any modification of the surface.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# Make data.
X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
Z = np.sin(R)

# Plot the surface.
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

# Customize the z axis.
ax.set_zlim(-1.01, 1.01)
ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.02f'))

# Add a color bar which maps values to colors.
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)

plt.show()
```

to

```
Z = np.sin(2*R)
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could evaluate `np.sin(a * R)` for a range of `a` values using [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
n = 10  # or however many intermediate arrays you want
a = np.linspace(1, 2, n)
interp_z = np.sin(a[:, None, None] * R[None])  # an (n, 40, 40) array
```

Now you can plot each of the intermediate arrays, save it as an image, then stitch the images together however you like:

```
for i, Z in enumerate(interp_z):
    ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, ...)
    fig.savefig('image_{}.png'.format(i))
```

Comment: I think this is the workflow the OP said he's currently using. He's looking for something like D3's ability to transition between frames.

Comment: Well then I'm afraid he's out of luck. Matplotlib was primarily designed for making static plots - there's no provision for any type of "transition" besides manually updating the states of the plot elements and redrawing the canvas on each frame.